# private pastebin-like open source application?

Tags: web-applications, syntax-highlighting, code-snippets, pastebin

I don't really know whether something like this exists, but well, I'll try to explain what I'm after.

I am sometimes gathering some of various snippets for common tasks I'm doing, like, for example, some longer database queries I perform, various linux commands for my daily tasks, and sometimes some php code for things I would have to otherwise search for in my previous projects.

Now, I would prefer to have some web-based solution, which would just let me paste my snippets and be kept there [with syntax higlighting of most languages]. However, the usual pastebins are not allowing things like tagging inputs, keeping track of history, authorization and so on. The more complex ones are not open source, and I can't host them myself (that's quite the necessity, because sometimes I'd like to cover some more sensitive data). I wonder whether there is something in between more suited to my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is stikked. Not as involved as you wanted, but it may be a start. It used the code igniter framework. http://code.google.com/p/stikked